# How to use siblings() and closest() in Geb test

Tags: groovy, geb

I am trying to write a script to click an icon which is a part of the table header. Each column in the table has this icon in it (ascending order and descending order sorting icons). I am using Geb to do this. Here is how I am trying to do it:

In my `SortingSpec.groovy` file:

```
header.closest("div.customSortDownLabel").click()
```

I also tried

```
header.siblings('div.customSortDownLabel').first().click()
```

In the `SortingPage.groovy` file:

```
header {
    grid.$(class: 'div.customHeaderLabel', text: 'Country')
}
```

In my html:

```
<div>
    <div class="customHeaderLabel">{{params.displayName}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="params.enableSorting" (click)="onSortRequested('asc', $event)" [ngClass]="ascSort" class="customSortDownLabel">
        <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-alt-down"></i></div>
    <div *ngIf="params.enableSorting" (click)="onSortRequested('desc', $event)" [ngClass]="descSort" class="customSortUpLabel">
</div>
```

None of them worked for me. It is not able to find the selector. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Error I see is:

> geb.error.RequiredPageContentNotPresent: The required page content 'header - SimplePageContent (owner: SortingGrid, args: [], value: null)' is not present

Comment: How about an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. a full HTML page, full Geb page and full Geb test reproducing your issue? Just condense your own code into the smallest set of files and contents which reproduce your problem. With your snippets I can only speculate and I do not want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

siblings() didnt work for me but next() worked for me. next() grabs the next sibling elements of the current context elements.

Example:
1. header.next().click() clicks the very next sibling

2. header.next("div.customSortDownLabel").click() looks for the very next sibling with the matching selector of 'div.customSortDownLabel' and then clicks it.

Comment: I am not sure.. Siblings() wasn't able to find the element

Answer (score 2):

That error looks like header isn't matching.  Assuming that grid matches, and you're using some Javascript framework like Angular to substitute 'Country' for params.displayName, I would guess that maybe Geb is failing to find header before 'Country' is substituted.  So, I would try making header wait for it:

```
header(wait: true) { grid.$(class: 'div.customHeaderLabel', text: 'Country') }
```

By the way, closest() goes in the wrong direction, to an ancestor, but siblings() looks good.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you also help me with the SIblings syntax? header.siblings('div.customSortDownLabel').first().click() . Should I use first() ? or using header.siblings('div.customSortDownLabel').click() would work?

Comment: It looks like there is only one sibling matching div.customSortDownLabel, so first() should be optional.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification